# Mícheál O'Searcoid, Metric Space, Theorem 1.2.2

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Searcoid writes:

> Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $u:X → R⊕$. Then $u ∈ δ(X)$ if, and only
>   if, $u$ is a pointlike function on $X$ and $0 ∈ u(X)$. In that case, there is a unique
>   $w ∈ X$ such that $u = δ_w$.
>
> **Proof**:
>   If $u ∈ δ(X)$, $u$ is a pointlike function and $0 ∈ u(X)$ by 1.2.4. On the other
>   hand, if $u$ is a pointlike function and there exists $w ∈ X$ with $u(w) = 0$, then
>   $u(b) = u(b) − u(w) ≤ d(b,w) ≤ u(b) + u(w) = u(b)$ for all $b ∈ X$. Therefore
>   $u(b) = d(b,w) = δ_w(b)$, yielding $u = δ_w$, and $w$ is unique by 1.2.2.
>
> **Theorem 1.2.2**
>   Suppose (X, d) is a metric space. The function $z → δz$ is a bijective function
>   from $X$ onto $δ(X)$.

However unless $u$ is injective, we can always have $u(w)=u(z)=0$, with $z\neq w$.

Seems for pointlike function, with  $0\in u(X)$ in general we will have pseudo metric space, not the metric space where $d(a,b)=0  \Rightarrow a=b$.

Please provide insight.

Comment: What is R⊕? ? ?

Comment: R⊕ is set of positive real number zero included.